# How to call accountManager.getUserData from a custom account that has been created with another app?

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager

I am creating two apps. The main app has included a login, where a custom account is created. With the second app I want to access the user data (refresh token is stored there) from the main app.

The main app is creating a custom account and the refresh token is stored via setUserData. Through the main app it is no problem to get the refresh token with

```java
mAccountManager.getUserData(account, KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN);
```

It works perfectly fine to retrieve the refresh token, if the both apps are signed with the same key.

But when I call this method and the apps are not signed with the same key:

```java
mAccountManager.getUserData(account, KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN);
```

I receive following error:

```
2019-10-01 12:01:51.143 5528-5528/at.exampleapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: at.exampleapp, PID: 5528
    java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10265 cannot get user data for accounts of type: accountType
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
        at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.getUserData(IAccountManager.java:1020)
        at android.accounts.AccountManager.getUserData(AccountManager.java:515)
        at eu.aal.dapas.component_auth.AccountAuthenticator.getExistingAccountRefreshToken(AccountAuthenticator.java:206)
        at eu.aal.dapas.component_auth.AccountAuthenticator.refreshAccessToken(AccountAuthenticator.java:138)
        at eu.aal.dapas.component_auth.DapasAccountManager.getAccessToken(DapasAccountManager.java:41)
        at at.e_nnovation.emma.apps.exampleapp.MainActivity.getUserDetails(MainActivity.java:196)
        at at.e_nnovation.emma.apps.exampleapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6600)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6577)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:781)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25912)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService.getUserData(AccountManagerService.java:1574)
        at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManager.java:77)
        at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService.onTransact(AccountManagerService.java:1100)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:735)
```

**So my questions are:**

1.) Is it possible at all to call the user data from a custom account with accountManager.getUserData(account, key) from another app?

2.) If not is there a way to get the refresh token from the custom account?

Comment: i'm also currently working with the account manager, i've managed to get this working by having both apps use the same package name when creating accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getUserData(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String)):

> This method requires the caller to have a signature match with the authenticator that owns the specified account.

So you need to have both apps signed with the same key.

Or you can just use `getAuthToken` and `invalidateAuthToken` in the second app and implement authenticator service in the first one. Just follow [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth)